# How to add custom documents properties to Excel from SL4

Tags: .net, silverlight, excel, interop, properties

I want to add a custom property to an Excel document from an OOB Silverlight application.

When I try to add the value I get the following exception:
*Could not convert an argument for the call to Add.*

> dynamic properties = document.CustomDocumentProperties;
>   properties.Add("A",true,4,"B");    //Could not convert an argument  for the call to Add.

I don't know that is the wrong argument, because in the exception I cannot see more details about the exception. I think that the problem is from MsoDocProperties. This property I didn't find in the SL API for Office, because of this I used the 4 value.
Can someone help me, or give me a hint?

Add method description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.documentproperties.add.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you included as a link the second parameter is of type boolean.  Yet you are passing the string "B" to that parameter.  I think you should be passing `false`.

Comment: I tried with:

> document.CustomDocumentProperties; properties.Add("A",true,4,"B")
but with the same result. I would used name parameters, but they aren't supported in SL. Some ideas?

Comment: @user855568: Are you sure 4 maps to MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString?  If the neum begins at 0 then it would be 3.

Answer (score 0):

I forget about the last param:

```
_properties.Add(name,true,4,value,false);
```

Comment: Does that really fix it? Are optional parameters not really optionaly when used with the dynamic data type.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question. Please mark this answer as accepted if you have.